# hashmap validation in spring

Tags: spring, validation

My hashmap is :

```
    HashMap h = new HashMap();
    HashMap h2 = new HashMap();
    List<HashMap> lh = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap ch;

    lh = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    ch = new HashMap();
    ch.put("op", "==");
    ch.put("value", "20dd1");
    lh.add(ch);
    h2.put("lOCATION", lh);



    lh = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    ch = new HashMap();
    ch.put("op", ">=");
    ch.put("value", "1239");
    lh.add(ch);

    ch = new HashMap();
    ch.put("op", "<=");
    ch.put("value", "1234");
    lh.add(ch);
    h2.put("invNO", lh);




    lh = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    ch = new HashMap();
    ch.put("op", ">=");
    ch.put("value", "1239");
    lh.add(ch);

    ch = new HashMap();
    ch.put("op", "<=");
    ch.put("value", "1234");
    lh.add(ch);
    h2.put("IssDate", lh);



    h.put("Invoice", h2);
```

I want to validate this hashmap (search jsp) for two condition:

1) type check (int/double/float etc)
2) range check like like entry invoice no. from, invoice no. to

My validate function is: (working)

```
1) Iterator iterator = typeCh.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        String key = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
        if (key.equals(field)) {
            String type = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
            if (type.equals("intValidator")) {
                try {
                    sent.put(field, "OK: " + Integer.parseInt(value));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    sent.put(field, "must be 0-9");
                }
            } else if (type.equals("decimalValidator")) {
                try {
                    sent.put(field, "OK: " + Double.parseDouble(value));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    sent.put(field, "must be double");
                }
        }

    }

2) int from = Integer.parseInt(val.get(1));
    int to = Integer.parseInt(val.get(2));

    if (from > to) {
        sent.put(field, "from must be less than to");
    } else {
        sent.put(field, "OK");
    }
```

I want to create these type of validations in spring.

How can i do these?
Pls Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement HashMap in the spring application context and share across the IOC using the following `util:map`. For that, first include `xmlns:util` in the schema (in your spring configuration file).

```
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

Then define your map:

```
<util:map id="typeCh"
    key-type="java.Lang.String"
    value-type="java.Lang.String"
    map-class="java.util.HashMap">
</util:map>
```

Then in your java source code:

```
@Resource Map<String, String> typeCh;
```

Populate the map once and send this to class having your validation logic.